# How to interpret BIP21 URI with `amount` specified twice?

Tags: bip21-uri

[BIP21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) includes the following grammar rule:

```
bitcoinparam   = [ amountparam / labelparam / messageparam / otherparam / reqparam ]
```

I'm not sure if this grammar rule allows to specify `amountparam` multiple times or not. An example might be:

`bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W?amount=20.3&amount=21&label=Luke-Jr` (amount twice intentionally)

The `amount` parameter is specified twice and I'm not sure what BIP21 parsers are supposed to do in this case. Personally, I would reject the URI as "not valid" because it feels like the safest option for payers. However, maybe only the first value (ie `20.3`) is to be considered or the latest one (ie `21`).

Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: FWIW, I created a PR (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/27928) and it shows how BIP21 is implemented in Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 0):

Per [ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) grammar, this would evaluate to a single amount field.

If it were to allow more 1 or more amount fields, it would be represented as `1*amount`. If it were to allow 1 OR two amount fields, it would be represented as `1*2amount`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. However, there is also: `bitcoinparams  = bitcoinparam [ "&" bitcoinparams ]` and so I can place `bitcoinparam` as many times as I want and not necessarily different ones. Right?